# Stacking notification bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I like the notification bars used in stackoverflow.  I have found a jQuery plugin which makes the notification bar possible with just a few lines, but this plugin does not seem to stack multiple notifications bars when required.

Does anyone know of a better plugin or how to get the plugin below to stack bars as more notifications become available?

http://www.dmitri.me/blog/notify-bar/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
...
<body>

  <div id="notificationArea"></div>

  <!-- rest of your website -->

</body>
</html>
```

Then to create notifications just do this in jquery:

```
$('#notificationArea').prepend('<div class="notification">This is my notification</div>');
```

its a bit basic, but this should do the trick, and because you are "prepending" you will get the stacking you are looking for. You can use `append()` too, but I was assuming you'd want the most recent notifications on the top.

To get the "X" (close) button just have a link in the notification with a class of `notifcationClose` and do:

```
$('.notificationClose').click(function(){ $('this').parents('.notification').remove(); })
```

Comment: `$('.notificationClose').click(function(){ $('this').parent().remove(); });` try that - the link has to be a direct decendent of the notification though.

Answer (score 2):

I know that you are looking only for bar plugin, but I write my opinion. Imagine that you have more than 2 notifications in this bar. It grows and it could fill more space than you would like to. Instead of viewing results of action, user will see only notifications to half display of monitor :)

Try to consider using bar notifications, if you know that you will have more than one notification in time often.

I recommend [jGrowl](http://stanlemon.net/pages/jgrowl) which is similar to the way that in OS X works. It is simple, good-looking and ready for many notifications in time.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this piece of Javascript that does just that.

```
// Show a message bar at the top of the screen to tell the user that something is going on.
// hideAfterMS - Optional argument. When supplied it hides the bar after a set number of milliseconds.
    function AdvancedMessageBar(hideAfterMS) {
        // Add an element to the top of the page to hold all of these bars.
        if ($('#barNotificationContainer').length == 0) 
        {               

        var barContainer = $('<div id="barNotificationContainer" style="width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"></div>');
        barContainer.prependTo('body');

        var barContainerFixed = $('<div id="barNotificationContainerFixed" style="width: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;"></div>');
        barContainerFixed.prependTo('body');
    }

    this.barTopOfPage = $('<div style="margin: 0px; background: orange; width: 100%; text-align: center; display: none; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: darkorange;"><table style="width: 100%; padding: 5px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="width: 20%; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;" class="leftMessage" ></td><td style="width: 60%; text-align: center;" class="messageCell"></td><td class="rightMessage" style="width: 20%; font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;"></td></tr></table></div>');
    this.barTopOfScreen = this.barTopOfPage.clone();

    this.barTopOfPage.css("background", "transparent");
    this.barTopOfPage.css("border-bottom-color", "transparent");
    this.barTopOfPage.css("color", "transparent");

    this.barTopOfPage.prependTo('#barNotificationContainer');
    this.barTopOfScreen.appendTo('#barNotificationContainerFixed');


    this.setBarColor = function (backgroundColor, borderColor) {     

        this.barTopOfScreen.css("background", backgroundColor);
        this.barTopOfScreen.css("border-bottom-color", borderColor);
    };

    // Sets the message in the center of the screen.
    // leftMesage - optional
    // rightMessage - optional
    this.setMessage = function (message, leftMessage, rightMessage) {
        this.barTopOfPage.find('.messageCell').html(message);
        this.barTopOfPage.find('.leftMessage').html(leftMessage);
        this.barTopOfPage.find('.rightMessage').html(rightMessage);

        this.barTopOfScreen.find('.messageCell').html(message);
        this.barTopOfScreen.find('.leftMessage').html(leftMessage);
        this.barTopOfScreen.find('.rightMessage').html(rightMessage);
    };


    this.show = function() {
        this.barTopOfPage.slideDown(1000);
        this.barTopOfScreen.slideDown(1000);
    };

    this.hide = function () {
        this.barTopOfPage.slideUp(1000);
        this.barTopOfScreen.slideUp(1000);
    };

    var self = this;   


    if (hideAfterMS != undefined) {
        setTimeout(function () { self.hide(); }, hideAfterMS);
    }    
}
```

To use it you must use jQuery and ensure there are no margins or padding on the body of your page.

The parameter that the AdvancedMessageBar takes is optional. If provided it will cause the bar to disappear after a certain amount of time in milliseconds.

```
var mBar = new AdvancedMessageBar(10000);
mBar.setMessage('This is my message', 'Left Message', 'Right Message');
mBar.show();
```

If you want to stack these then just create more AdvancedMessageBar objects and they'll automatically stack.